# Trouble getting CSS animation to work when AJAX call

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, animation

So I am making a website and can make the CSS animation work for when the page is first called but I want it to call everytime the AJAX function is called. Here is the javascript XML call which works

```
function XML(infoId)
{
var xmlHttp = xmlHttpObjCreate();
    if (!xmlHttp) {
        alert("The browser doesn't support this action.");
        return;
    }

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            elemObj = document.getElementById('textbox');
            elemObj.innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
            elemObj.className = "bounceInUp";
          }
    }

    // Append GET data to identify which quote we want
    var reqURL = "FILE_NAME_HERE_?infoId=" + infoId;
    xmlHttp.open("GET", reqURL, true);
    xmlHttp.send();
}
```

Here is an example of what calls the function

Here is the CSS animation code which is named is "bounceInUp"

```
#textbox {
width: 100%;
background-color: transparent;
height: 200px;
color: #0000FF;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 22px; 
overflow: auto;
padding: 10;


-webkit-animation: bounceInUp 1200ms ease-out;
-moz-animation: bounceInUp 1200ms ease-out;
-o-animation: bounceInUp 1200ms ease-out;
animation: bounceInUp 1200ms ease-out;

}  

@-webkit-keyframes bounceInUp {
  0%, 60%, 75%, 90%, 100% {
-webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
        transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  }

  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 3000px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 3000px, 0);
  }

   60% {
 opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -20px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, -20px, 0);
 }

     75% {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0);
 }

      90% {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -5px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, -5px, 0);
  }

       100% {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   }
   }

@keyframes bounceInUp {
  0%, 60%, 75%, 90%, 100% {
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
        transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  }

  0% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 3000px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 3000px, 0);
  }

  60% {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -20px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, -20px, 0);
  }

   75% {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0);
  }

   90% {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -5px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, -5px, 0);
  }

   100% {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
 }


 .bounceInUp {
    -webkit-animation-name: bounceInUp;
      animation-name: bounceInUp;
 }
```

I apologize for all the code but I want to make sure everything is here that someone may need to help me. So as of right now the css animation only runs when the page is first loaded not when the XML function is called.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are already attaching the animation via the #textbox CSS selector.  And your AJAX call adds a class name that appears to have the exact same animation properties that are already applied to the textbox via the #textbox rule.

In order to get your animation to fire again, I suspect you need to clear the animation CSS property off of your #textbox before the AJAX call is sent, then your AJAX call will reapply the animation.  You can do this a variety of ways, one off the top of my head would be to create a separate class that clears the animation and apply that classname to #textbox before you do your xmlHttp.send(), that way the textbox is back to a non-animated state before your success handler from the AJAX call reapplies the animation.

To simplify it, you may just want to remove the animation properties from the #textbox CSS rule and just  apply and remove the .bounceInUp class name to the element when you want the animation to run.  I think that's a cleaner approach.

Comment: Ok so i am thinking of doing your simplified method. I removed the animation properties from my #textbox. How would I go about applying and removing the .bounceInUp class to the element I choose.

Comment: Yes, that should work.  Also, see the answer from Martin Cortez about using the classList.remove and classList.add.  Those should ensure you are only removing the className you want to remove in the event there are multiple class names applied to the element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList):

```
    this.classList.remove('bounceInUp'); 
    this.classList.add('bounceInUp');
```

That will re-apply the class and make the bounce happen again. It is simpler and more readable than setTimeout. You're fine with `classList` since you're using keyframes - each will work on IE10 and above.